# Error 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: networking, linux-networking, sniffing

I have recently installed a (cross platform) client server application consisting of a web server backend and a thick (dumb) desktop client.

I have been able to connect to the server and run the Ubuntu desktop client successfully, however, when a colleague installed the client application on their Windows 10 laptop, the got the following error:

> [Error 10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it

I have **SSH** installed and running on the Linux server.

This is what I've done so far, to try and solve the problem:

**1.** run `ps aux | grep ssh` to make sure SSH is running on server:

```
root      4359  0.0  0.1  65520  6304 ?        Ss   Sep02   0:02 /usr/sbin/sshd -D    
root     19148  0.0  0.1  95400  6704 ?        Ss   08:23   0:00 sshd: morpheous [priv]    
morpheo+ 19166  0.0  0.0  95400  3380 ?        S    08:23   0:00 sshd: morpheous@pts/0
```

**2.** run `netstat -l` to make sure port 8000 is being listened to:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16673    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11592    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11597    /var/run/docker.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11601    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15199    /run/docker/libnetwork/c691c7be0884cd7e163479e2dca860cec5877a0dc01ed98a50e22d236d70b7e0.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9616     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9623     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9631     /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9644     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15072    /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
```

**3.** Used putty from the Windows machine, to try to connect to the server. However, when presented with the Linux CLI and prompted to login, when I enter valid credentials, I get the error message: **Access denied**

**4.** I [obtained the IP address of the windows machine](http://whatismyipaddress.com/), and then checked `/var/log/auth.log` on the server machine to see if the IP address of the windows machine was in there (to see if the machine had been refused connection as reported by the Tryton client app). **THERE WAS NO RECORD OF THE IP ADDRESS IN THE LOG FILE!**

Can someone help with the required steps needed to diagnose and fix this problem?

**[[UPDATE]]**

It turns out that my friend was using the wrong IP address on the Windows client!. However, as I have wasted an entire day trying to get to the bottom of this, my question is this:

**ASSUMING THE CLIENT IS ATTEMPTING TO CONNECT TO THE CORRECT MACHINE (i.e. USING CORRECT IP ADDRESS)**, is there a way I can (on the server) view/record all **HTTP and HTTPS** requests coming to the server machine?

How can I do that?

Comment: When somebody is connecting or trying to connect to the wrong server no amount of logging on the correct server will help. ... With regards to logging: on the **default log level** most services will only log requests they can **recognize** as valid (or illegal) in **the correct protocol** and trying to connect with an incorrect protocol to a valid port won't result in a log entry. I.e. connecting with an SSH client to the HTTPS port of a web server won't be logged. But a request for a forbidden resource like an .htaccess file will be logged. A very verbose debug log level may record more ...

Comment: @HBruijn I'll clarify my question.  I thought it was obvious that I wasn't trying to check for logins attempts into remote machines from a different server. I guess I'll have to be more explicit.